# How to get cURL response parameters?

Tags: php, curl

I'm pretty much new to the cURL, so I need some basic help.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_PRIVATE        => true,
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

With result I receive array with:
array (size=27)

```
'url' => string 'http://www.example.com/' (length=23)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 578
  'request_size' => int 54
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 2.488353
  'namelookup_time' => float 2.3E-5
  'connect_time' => float 2.3E-5
  'pretransfer_time' => float 4.1E-5
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 349651
  'speed_download' => float 140515
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 349651
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.552837
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '1.11.11.111' (length=11)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 80
```

The problem is when I get on http://www.example.com, I'm automatically moved to http://www.example.com/param1=EP2AED6AEBqAID;sid=5aaca7ddb04eb5d;

Question is, how I am supposed to get that parameters?

Comment: Do you know how you get redirected by javascript or by header redirect?

Comment: Getting redirected by javascript.

Comment: you have already set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` as `true` so there must be no redirection problem. Problem is somewhere else in your code. I would like to know the value of `$url` that you used to set `CURLOPT_URL`.

Comment: Good example is page: http://www.booking.com . It works pretty much the same. When you get on booking.com it redirects to http://www.booking.com/index.pl.html?label=gen111nr-1DCAID;sid=b25cbb04eb5d;sb_price_type=total&

And I'm in need of those parameters to, for example, create a search.

Comment: If you get redirected then curl won't be able to help you. If you know which part of the js code do the redirect then you can for example get page html and parse it and extract the redirect url params from js code?